# ncmpcpp is damaged after experienced a crash

Tags: cache, mpd

My problem appeared with **ncmpcpp** the console music player.

I've used ncmpcpp to open a .pls file from the `Browser` window and it crashed perhaps due to encoding problems. Since then, Every time I launch it, I see the playlist I tried to open in the playlists editor, and when I try to delete it I get an error that this playlist doesn't exist. Yet it is still there in the playlists editor.

Is there a way to clear the cache for this program?

I tried to uninstall the program, reboot and install it again but no luck.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in `~/.ncmpcpp/` to see if there's anything in there which relates.  Or just remove `~/.ncmpcpp/` entirely if there's nothing you want to keep from the previous install.

You should also check `~/music/` which appears to be a default directory for some content.  Additionally, check the `ncmpcpp` config file which might point to additional directories for content.

Comment: Nothing there, there is a file named `error.log` in `~/.ncmpcpp/` but it is empty.

Comment: Have added another option.

Comment: You were right, thanks. It seems that Because this file was invoked from my `~/Music` directory itself it kept showing up in the playlist editor